# is it possible to mirror lattice edits?

Tags: mirror, lattice

I'm using a lattice to make late-game body proportion edits to a character. When using the lattice in edit mode I noticed there is no mirror option nor is there a way to add a mirror modifier to it. Seems kinda odd to me that there wouldent be an option to do this.

Comment: As @Rumen Belev mentioned, lattice object comes without native mirror attributes. Here's one addon [Lattice Mirror](https://blendermarket.com/products/lattice-mirror) that can do real-time symmetrical edits for lattice, just be aware the axis is only effective locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mirror a Lattice object due to the nature of this object.

If you want to edit symmetrically (for example with X symmetry) Duplicate Linked (Alt+D) the Lattice and scale it along X axis using your 3D cursor placed at world origin.

Now add the two lattices as modifiers and continue editing.
Once you are done you can apply the modifiers to keep the object's deformation.